# Bootstrap 3 issue with columns shifting

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-masonry

I am having an issue with my layout and I cant seem to figure it out.

I am using Bootstrap 3 with masonry. Right before masonry loads (or when its disabled) the container has 4 items in it like I expect it to. However, as soon as masonry is applied, it is knocking down the 4th item to a new row.

Is there anything obvious in the code below that would cause this? There is no CSS styling applied to my content or from masonry it self. It is just 3 col divs being placed in a 12 col container.

Masonry is adding the positions to it to make them staggered but is also knocking down my 4th one.

Any ideas of what I can do to keep 4 per row?

Notice: The style position in the image below is added from masonry and not something I have on my end prior.

[image]

```
    <div class="container">
   <ul class="thumbnails list-unstyled posts">
            <!-- Submission Block ID# 1-->
      <li class="col-md-3 item Dog" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;">
         <div style="padding: 0" class="thumbnail">
            <div style="padding:4px">
               <img src="uploads/nalaHUS123.png" style="width: 100%">
            </div>
            <div class="caption">
               <h4 class="">Nala  <small>(<span class="petType">Dog</span>) (1)</small></h4>
               <p>Shes a wonder pup!</p>
               <center><button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="button"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Vote&nbsp;&nbsp;</button></center>
            </div>
            <div style="text-align: left" class="modal-footer">
               <div class="progress">
                  <div style="width: 60%;" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuenow="60" role="progressbar" class="progress-bar">
                     <span class="sr-only">60% Complete</span>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-4"><b>Rank</b><br><small>3rd Place</small></div>
                  <div class="col-md-2"></div>
                  <div class="col-md-4"><b>Raised</b><br><small>$130.00</small></div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </li>
      <!-- End Submission Block ID# 1-->  
            <!-- Submission Block ID# 2-->
      <li class="col-md-3 item Cat">
         <div style="padding: 0" class="thumbnail">
            <div style="padding:4px">
               <img src="uploads/simbaHUS123.png" style="width: 100%">
            </div>
            <div class="caption">
               <h4 class="">Simba  <small>(<span class="petType">Cat</span>) (2)</small></h4>
               <p>Shes a wonder pup!</p>
               <center><button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="button"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Vote&nbsp;&nbsp;</button></center>
            </div>
            <div style="text-align: left" class="modal-footer">
               <div class="progress">
                  <div style="width: 60%;" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuenow="60" role="progressbar" class="progress-bar">
                     <span class="sr-only">60% Complete</span>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-4"><b>Rank</b><br><small>3rd Place</small></div>
                  <div class="col-md-2"></div>
                  <div class="col-md-4"><b>Raised</b><br><small>$250.00</small></div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </li>
      <!-- End Submission Block ID# 2-->  
            <!-- Submission Block ID# 3-->
      <li class="col-md-3 item Bird">
         <div style="padding: 0" class="thumbnail">
            <div style="padding:4px">
               <img src="uploads/boboHUS123.png" style="width: 100%">
            </div>
            <div class="caption">
               <h4 class="">BoBo  <small>(<span class="petType">Bird</span>) (3)</small></h4>
               <p>Shes a wonder pup!</p>
               <center><button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="button"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Vote&nbsp;&nbsp;</button></center>
            </div>
            <div style="text-align: left" class="modal-footer">
               <div class="progress">
                  <div style="width: 60%;" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuenow="60" role="progressbar" class="progress-bar">
                     <span class="sr-only">60% Complete</span>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-4"><b>Rank</b><br><small>3rd Place</small></div>
                  <div class="col-md-2"></div>
                  <div class="col-md-4"><b>Raised</b><br><small>$323.00</small></div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </li>
      <!-- End Submission Block ID# 3-->  
            <!-- Submission Block ID# 4-->
      <li class="col-md-3 item Bird">
         <div style="padding: 0" class="thumbnail">
            <div style="padding:4px">
               <img src="uploads/frankHUS123.png" style="width: 100%">
            </div>
            <div class="caption">
               <h4 class="">Frank  <small>(<span class="petType">Bird</span>) (4)</small></h4>
               <p>Shes a wonder pup!</p>
               <center><button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="button"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Vote&nbsp;&nbsp;</button></center>
            </div>
            <div style="text-align: left" class="modal-footer">
               <div class="progress">
                  <div style="width: 60%;" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuenow="60" role="progressbar" class="progress-bar">
                     <span class="sr-only">60% Complete</span>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-4"><b>Rank</b><br><small>3rd Place</small></div>
                  <div class="col-md-2"></div>
                  <div class="col-md-4"><b>Raised</b><br><small>$323.00</small></div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </li> 
         </ul>
   <nav id="pagination" style="display: none;"><a href="?page=2" class="next"></a></nav>      
</div>
```

UPDATE:

This is what it looks like if I turn masonry off:

[image]

Comment: Here is a Fiddle of what I am referring to: 
http://jsfiddle.net/3Upq3/2/embedded/result/ It has masonry applied to it and it now shifts to 3 per col instead of 4

Comment: Works fine if you remove the gutter from the masonry options. See http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/3Upq3/6/embedded/result/

Comment: @koala_dev - I am very disappointing that its been there the whole time and I thought gutter was something to do with the spacing at the bottom :/ ... That fixed it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `gutter` masonry option is adding horizontal space between the columns so they don't fit in a single row, remove it and it should work fine.

See this **[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/3Upq3/6/embedded/result/)**

Comment: Yep that's it. I was JUST about to write that!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<ul class="thumbnails list-unstyled">
```

as opposed to

```
<ul class="thumbnails list-unstyled posts">
```

Comment: Is `.posts` already a defiend bootstrap class? I added that myself as its my container that masonry uses to know where the new items will be.

Comment: Changed it for the heck of it and it was the same problem :/

Comment: When you remove `.posts`, the plugin doesn't know the container to run on. As said in the OP, it works fine without the plugin started which is what happened in your demo; it didn't apply masonry to it.

Answer (score 0):

From Bootstrap: `Content should be placed within columns, and only columns may be immediate children of rows.`

From what I can see, you have `.container > .col-md-3`

When you should have `.container > .row > .col-md-3`

Comment: I gave that a try but ran into the same issue; only happens once masonry is initiated but its not applying any styling other than the position left to right within the main container so still not sure whats going on

Comment: what's your css for `.item`